# How to parse from SQL Time (String) to java.sql.Time?

Tags: java, sql, parsing, time

i have a database with a Time field. When i get the fields with a php, i receive the Time field as a String, by JSON.

The string i recive is like this: `08:00:00`

ok, all work's fine here, but i need to have that String in java.sql.Time format.

There is a easy way to do it?

code:

```
String hour1=retrieveHourFromPHPSqlConnection();
Time a=hour1;
```

how to transform hour1 into Time?

thanks

Comment: It's unclear where PHP comes in here... where is everything running? Why can't you just get the data from JDBC?

Comment: What do you need `java.sql.Time` for? Normally you would only use it whenever you're about to `INSERT` a time field, not when you `SELECT` it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) I suggest you to use this :

```
java.sql.Time myTime = java.sql.Time.valueOf(hour1);
```

Takes a String in hh:mm:ss format and gives you a java.sql.Time object.

It's valid at least from Java 1.4.2 up to Java 7.

Comment: I saw above comment as `it works! thanks! – NullPointerException`. Read again and realised it's the username :D

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha haha, nice one :D